# When I use gather() twice, my resulting tibble is much larger than it should be

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a tibble of US-North Korea imports and exports over the past 20 years, and many of the column names are the names of months, titled IJAN for import months and EJAN for export months, so I used gather() twice to try and get them in the right tidydata format.

Here is my original tibble:

```
      # A tibble: 26 x 29
   year  CTY_CODE CTYNAME    IJAN  IFEB  IMAR  IAPR  IMAY  IJUN  IJUL  IAUG  ISEP  IOCT  INOV  IDEC   IYR  EJAN  EFEB  EMAR  EAPR  EMAY  EJUN  EJUL  EAUG  ESEP
   <chr> <chr>    <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 1992  5790     Korea, N~    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0. 0.       0.    0. 0.     0.   0.100  0.   0.    0.    0.     0.   0.    0.   
 2 1993  5790     Korea, N~    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0. 0.       0.    0. 0.     0.   0.     0.   0.    0.    0.     0.   0.    0.   
 3 1994  5790     Korea, N~    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0. 0.       0.    0. 0.     0.   0.     0.   0.    0.    0.200  0.   0.    0.   
 4 1995  5790     Korea, N~    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0. 0.       0.    0. 0.     0.   0.     6.60 0.    0.    4.20   0.   0.    0.200
 5 1996  5790     Korea, N~    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0. 0.       0.    0. 0.     0.   0.     0.   0.400 0.    0.     0.   0.    0.100
 6 1997  5790     Korea, N~    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0. 0.       0.    0. 0.     0.   0.     0.   0.    0.100 0.     2.00 0.    0.300
 7 1998  5790     Korea, N~    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0. 0.       0.    0. 0.     0.   0.     4.00 0.    0.    0.100  0.   0.300 0.   
 8 1999  5790     Korea, N~    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0. 0.       0.    0. 0.     0.   0.100  0.   0.    0.300 0.     1.10 0.500 0.500
 9 2000  5790     Korea, N~    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0. 0.100    0.    0. 0.100  2.50 0.100  0.   0.    0.    0.     0.   0.100 0.   
10 2001  5790     Korea, N~    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0. 0.       0.    0. 0.     0.   0.     0.   0.    0.    0.     0.   0.    0.   
# ... with 16 more rows, and 4 more variables: EOCT <dbl>, ENOV <dbl>, EDEC <dbl>, EYR <dbl>
```

The first time I use gather(), to work on the import months, it works fine

```
USNKTrade <- USNKTrade %>% gather(contains("I"), key="month", value="ImportAmount")
```

leads to

```
# A tibble: 338 x 18
   year  CTY_CODE CTYNAME       EJAN  EFEB  EMAR  EAPR  EMAY  EJUN  EJUL  EAUG  ESEP  EOCT  ENOV  EDEC    EYR month ImportAmount
   <chr> <chr>    <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
 1 1992  5790     Korea, North  0.   0.100  0.   0.    0.    0.     0.   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.     0.100 IJAN            0.
 2 1993  5790     Korea, North  0.   0.     0.   0.    0.    0.     0.   0.    0.    0.    2.00  0.     2.00  IJAN            0.
 3 1994  5790     Korea, North  0.   0.     0.   0.    0.    0.200  0.   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.     0.200 IJAN            0.
 4 1995  5790     Korea, North  0.   0.     6.60 0.    0.    4.20   0.   0.    0.200 0.    0.500 0.100 11.6   IJAN            0.
 5 1996  5790     Korea, North  0.   0.     0.   0.400 0.    0.     0.   0.    0.100 0.    0.    0.     0.500 IJAN            0.
 6 1997  5790     Korea, North  0.   0.     0.   0.    0.100 0.     2.00 0.    0.300 0.    0.100 0.     2.50  IJAN            0.
 7 1998  5790     Korea, North  0.   0.     4.00 0.    0.    0.100  0.   0.300 0.    0.    0.    0.     4.40  IJAN            0.
 8 1999  5790     Korea, North  0.   0.100  0.   0.    0.300 0.     1.10 0.500 0.500 0.500 0.600 7.70  11.3   IJAN            0.
 9 2000  5790     Korea, North  2.50 0.100  0.   0.    0.    0.     0.   0.100 0.    0.    0.    0.     2.70  IJAN            0.
10 2001  5790     Korea, North  0.   0.     0.   0.    0.    0.     0.   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.500  0.500 IJAN            0.
# ... with 328 more rows
```

but when I try and do the same with the exports, using

```
USNKTrade <- USNKTrade %>% gather(starts_with("E"), key="month", value="ExportAmount")
```

I then get a tibble that is about 4000 rows long, when in fact I want a tibble that is only twice as big as the previous one (so that every import and export month has its own row).

Help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput` and the expected output based on that

Comment: I think the issue is that you have applied `gather` command successively. When you 1st applied `gather` on `contains("I")` columns those column were moved to rows. Now on the resultant `data.frame` you are applying `gather` with `starts_with("E")`. Obviously it will lead to far more rows as rows with `I` columns will get multiplied too.

Comment: Note that it is better to use `starts_with()` since `contains()` will also detect the `E` and `I` that are not first letters.

Comment: @hpesoj626 at least whatever columns has been shared by OP as part of question it doesn't seem that there is conflict with `E` and `I`. Perhaps OP has smartly chosen `starts_with` for `E` otherwise there were overlaps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach. Use `starts_with()` instead of `contains()` because some months might contain E or I not only in the first letter. On the second gather, note that I have deselected the newly created columns `ImportAmount`, and `ImportMonth` as well as the column `year`.

```
year <- 1992:2001
EJAN <- rnorm(10)
IJAN <- rnorm(10)
EFEB <- rnorm(10)
IFEB <- rnorm(10)

df <- data.frame(year, EJAN, IJAN, EFEB, IFEB)
df %>% gather(starts_with("E"), key = ImportMonth, value = ImportAmount) %>%
  gather(starts_with("I"), key = ExportMonth, value = ExportAmount, -ImportAmount, -ImportMonth, - year)

#    year ImportMonth ImportAmount ExportMonth ExportAmount
# 1  1992        EJAN      -1.1528        IJAN      0.94967
# 2  1993        EJAN       0.1165        IJAN      0.86506
# 3  1994        EJAN       0.2553        IJAN     -0.05108
# 4  1995        EJAN      -0.8516        IJAN     -0.50873
# 5  1996        EJAN      -0.3014        IJAN      0.50614
# 6  1997        EJAN       1.4017        IJAN      1.73527
# 7  1998        EJAN       0.8019        IJAN     -0.71507
# 8  1999        EJAN       1.7179        IJAN     -0.32709
# 9  2000        EJAN      -1.2478        IJAN     -1.07364
# 10 2001        EJAN      -1.0491        IJAN     -1.83764
# ...
# 40 2001        EFEB       1.2181        IFEB      0.76118
```

Answer (score 0):

Though `OP` has not provided reproducible data but it seems that problem is that `OP` has applied `gather` recursively on `data.frame`.

```
 #The columns containing "I" will move to row after below command
 USNKTrade %>% gather(contains("I"), key="month", value="ImportAmount")

#Now below command will add for more rows
USNKTrade <- USNKTrade %>% gather(starts_with("E"), key="month", value="ExportAmount")
```

The feasible solution could be:

```
USNKTrade %>% select_at(vars(year, CTY_CODE, CTYNAME, contains("I"))) %>%
           gather(contains("I"), key="month", value="ImportAmount") %>%
inner_join(USNKTrade %>% select_at(vars(year, CTY_CODE, CTYNAME, starts_with("E"))) %>%
              starts_with(contains("E"), key="month", value="ImportAmount"),
         by = c("year", "CTY_CODE", "CTYNAME", "month"))
```

Approach is to first select only columns needed for `ImportAmount` and then apply `gather`. Now select only columns needed for `ExportAmount` and then apply `gather`. Merge both sets.

It has been assumed that `"year", "CTY_CODE", "CTYNAME", "month"` will be `key` columns for the joining.